# Shaking Screen of Application

Tags: html, css, angularjs, responsive-design, resize

[Shaking screen demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ju0su32po4oiuc/Rec_007.mp4?dl=0)

When I resize my window, then screens begins to shaking.
Please watch video for more confirmation.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Code

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: <div ng-view ng-animate-children class="body-content" style="margin:1em;" ng-style="styleCtrl.style(styleCtrl.fontFace,styleCtrl.fontSize)">

        </div>

Comment: its simple , its just that something happens to be loading and removing itself over and over again , due to this your page is overflowing which is causing the scroll bars to appear and disappear which in turn makes your page DANCE Or in more technical terms causing your page to be constantly in a state of auto adjustment

Comment: Can you please provide solution for it?

Comment: this is something you have to do bcoz i dont know whats being loaded and removed constantly , try opening the console of google chrome and checking for changes in the DOM (Changes are highlighted) , then traverse the dom and find the issue

Comment: Hi All... This code fixed it.
body {
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This much of code fixed this issue.

```
   body {
      overflow-y:scroll;
    }
```